# How to cut a circle from a different shapes of bitmap in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

How can i cut a circle from a different shapes of bitmap in android.

I tried this code, but some images are stretched:

```
    public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
    int targetWidth = 240;
    int targetHeight = 200;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth,
            targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
            ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
            (Math.min(((float) targetWidth),
                    ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
            Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap,new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                    sourceBitmap.getHeight()),
            new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
    return targetBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a circular cut of an image, you need to find the largest square that centers the image. Considering this, following line fixes your stretching problem:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, radius, radius, ThumbnailUtils.OPTIONS_RECYCLE_INPUT);
```

This method creates a circular cut of the target bitmap:

```
private Bitmap getCircularBitmap(int radius, Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius, conf);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

    // creates a centered bitmap of the desired size
    bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, radius, radius, ThumbnailUtils.OPTIONS_RECYCLE_INPUT);
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    paint.setShader(shader);
    RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, radius, radius);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);

    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: It is the radius value of the circle you want to create. As you know, it should be half of min(width, height). In your situation, 100 will be okay. Please try and let me know.

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer. Change this line: "RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, radius*2, radius*2);". The parameters should be "(0, 0, radius, radius)". Is it ok?

Comment: it doesnt make it circle its effects only in one corner

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a `BitmapShader`.

The idea is to use a `Paint` with a `BitmapShader` to draw a texture using the bitmap.  Then you just draw a circle on the canvas.

Here is an excellent example of using the `BitmapShader`.  In this example, a rectangle with rounded corners is drawn, but it could just as easily be a circle.

[Android Recipe #1, image with rounded corners](http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/comment-page-1/)